# Excel-like filtering in kendo grid is not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am looking for excel like filtering in kendo grid. From Telerik demos I could find a demo with this feature like below:

```
 .Columns(columns =>
 {
     columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));                
 });
```

Where as if I implement "**.Filterable(ftb=>ftb.Multi(true))**" in my code, I am getting an error like "error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type". Can someone please guide me how to implement this feature.

Comment: Could you provide more of the grid code so we can see the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true)` should just work.

Note that Excel-like filtering was only released [two weeks ago](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/q1-2015). Did you update Kendo UI to version 2015 Q1?

[What's new](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui):

> **Grid**
>
> The Grid adds highly requested functionality, such as:
>
> - Excel-like filtering, i.e. a multi-select checkboxes option as part of the filtering menu

Comment: Hi Vash, Thanks a lot for the help. Oops!! I didn't update to latest version of Kendo UI. Let me update and try.. Once again Thanks a lot :)